# url for multiple category

Tags: php, categories

I need some help here. I have a script here for category selection. When i use on url www.domain.com/zone.php?cat=Apple it works and shows items in Apple category

However I would like to have 2 or more categories in the url like www.domain.com/zone.php?cat=Apple&cat=Orange&cat=Pear so that it shows all items in Apple, Orange and Pear. How do i do that from the below.

```
if (isset($_GET['cat']) && strtolower($_GET['cat'])!=='all'){
    $cat = DB::LimitQuery('category', array(
'condition' =>'name="'.$_GET['cat'].'"',
));

    $condition = array( 
            "(city_id = '0' OR find_in_set({$city['id']},city_id))",
            'product' => $cat[0]['id'],
            "begin_time <  {$daytime}",
            );
} else {
    $condition = array( 
            "(city_id = '0' OR find_in_set({$city['id']},city_id))",
            "begin_time <  {$daytime}",
            );      
}
```

Comment: Hi All, anyone has any solutions? Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

well you're doing it wrong if you want to have more categories you must set more `GET` parameters to catch it

```
$_GET['cat1']
$_GET['cat2']
$_GET['cat3']
```

but if you want a lot of categories in single parameter, delimit the categories with any character that would be encoded in the url correctly like `,` so it will be like this

www.domain.com/zone.php?cat=Apple&,Orange,Pear

and `explode()` it on the PHP side

```
$cats = explode($_GET['cat'],',');
```

Comment: First need to be delimiter. `explode(',', $_GET['cat'])`:)

Comment: Can i ask how do i do that? sorry i am not very experience with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
www.domain.com/zone.php?cat[]=Apple&cat[]=Orange&cat[]=Pear
```

It will create **array** in `$_GET['cat']`.

And in php make:

```
$condition = array( 
            "(city_id = '0' OR find_in_set({$city['id']},city_id))",
            'product IN ( '.implode(','.$_POST['cat'].')',
            "begin_time <  {$daytime}",
            );
```

***BUT*** you need to check that values for avoid injections.

Comment: I don't know how your DB class looks like, so it's approximate condition. Show mysql error after you change query.

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['arr']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['arr'];
        var_dump($id);
    }
    ?>


<?php $array =array('apple','orange','banana');
    $array = http_build_query(array('arr'=>$array));
    var_dump($array);
?>     

 <a href="index.php?<?php echo $array;?>">click</a>
```

i hope this will help you!